# I have two for loops in Jinja. (Django Project) I want to save the forloop.counter for the first loop to a variable and use in the secodn loop

Tags: html, django, for-loop, jinja2

I can't get the correct loop counter variable to save - I want a similar functionality to the enumerate in python, or just a way to store my variables for the next for loop.

```
{% for boards, value_dict in my_dict.items %}
    **{{ forloop.counter }}** <---- gets the correct loop index I need
    {% for mode, platform_dict in value_dict.items %}
        // I have no way of saving the above value, if I call forloop.counter in this line it gets the counter for the wrong forloop
        **// I need to use the index above in this line.**
        {% for mode, platform_dict in value_dict.items %}
          **// I also need the same variable here** 
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

What I tried using :

- {% with counter=forloop.counter %} (in first loop set this)
- {% with forloop.counter as counter %}
- {set counter = {{forloopcounter}} (in first loop set this)
- Using loop.index
- Using forloop.parent.count

This seems to be a very simple thing I want to do yet I can seem to find the right syntax to do it. Also using the

Comment: Is it possible to explain *what* you aim to achieve, not *how*. Likely there are more effective solutions than a nested `{% for ... %}` loop, especially since these are inefficient.

Comment: Yes. So I have a list of dictionaries. And each dictionary has a key that has another dictionary. I don't see a way to iterate through everything without nested for loops.

Comment: Pro tip : Write a *summarized* title and put the rest of the explanation in the body. You can change it to something like "How do i save for loop counter in a variable?"

Comment: @user16580315: can you give an example how the dictionary structure looks like, and what the expected output should be?

Comment: So I ran a test that printed a json file and I put that into dictionaries. I mainly just need the loop number because I am creating an accordian collapsable and I need a way to differentiate between the loops so they can open and close seperately